# Implicit conversion with a generic type failing for an interface type

Tags: c#, type-inference

```cs
        private struct Maybe<T>
        {
            private readonly T value;
            private readonly bool hasValue;

            private Maybe(T value)
            {
                this.value = value;
                hasValue = true;
            }

            public static implicit operator Maybe<T>(T value) =>
                value == null ? new Maybe<T>() : new Maybe<T>(value);
        }

        private static Maybe<byte> OK()
        {
            return 5;
        }

        private static Maybe<IEnumerable<byte>> NotOK()
        {
            var e = new[] { 1, 2, 3 }.Select(x => (byte)x);
            Console.WriteLine(e.GetType().Name);
            return e;
        }
```

Fiddle (don't use): https://dotnetfiddle.net/NxAw9l

**Updated fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/NrARTl**

Some generic type is failing for implicit conversion at above code. See the `Ok()` and `NotOk()` function calls and return types. A complex generic type is failing and I dont' understand why. I have simplified this from a function of a return type of `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>>`. This `IEnumerable<T>` still fails. I think If I can understand why this fails, I'd solve the real one too I suppose. Thanks for your help and time.

Here is the error message if you'd like:

```
Error    CS0029    Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<byte>' to 'Maybe<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<byte>>'
```

**Update:** Returning Byte[] from the NotOK() can't work because in my real source code I have a LINQ query I have to depend on its lazy-deferred execution (i.e It has to be strictly returning IEnumerable) (see alike answer => https://stackoverflow.com/a/63880804/5917087).

Comment: Did you mean to make your dotnetfiddle netcore? Because as net4.7.2 the error is completely different

Comment: I didn't honestly. I was just put it there to help others to speed up. I'm using C# 6.0 with .NET 4.8.

Comment: You should probably ifx the fiddle so it shows the same error then

Comment: When I open the link it shows 4.7.2 for me though.

Comment: And what happens if you try to run it? I get `Compilation error (line 16, col 53): ; expected`

Comment: Ah okay I fixed that. See the link. (Don't know why it errors about lambda return)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The C# standard currently does not allow implicit conversions from or to interfaces.

This is a well-known problem when implementing a `Maybe<T>` (or `Optional<T>`, as it is often called) type in C#. There is an ongoing discussion about this on the C# language github forum:

- https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/14186

---

As a workaround, you could make the `Maybe<T>` constructor `internal` and add a static non-generic helper class:

```
private static class Maybe
{
    public static Maybe<T> From<T>(T value) => 
        value == null ? new Maybe<T>() : new Maybe<T>(value);
}
```

which allows you to use type inference and write `Maybe.From(a)`, which is a bit shorter than `new Maybe<IEnumerable<byte>>(a)`.

Comment: Ah this is the closest thing I am doing right now. See this extended answer => https://dotnetfiddle.net/btd13e

I think there's no way I can think of as a workaround as like your answer.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to extend @Heinzi's answer:

You could also use extension methods:

```
static class MaybeExtensions
{
    public static Maybe<T> AsMaybe<T>(this T value)
    {
        return new Maybe<T>(value);
    }

    public static Maybe<TResult> AsMaybe<T, TResult>(this T value)
        where T : unmanaged
        where TResult : unmanaged
    {
        return new Maybe<TResult>(Unsafe.As<T, TResult>(ref value));
    }
}
```

And in your caller methods, you could use them like:

```
private static Maybe<IEnumerable<byte>> NotOK()
{
    var e = new[] { 1, 2, 3 }.Select(x => (byte)x);
    return e.AsMaybe();
}

private static Maybe<byte> OK()
{
    return 5.AsMaybe<int, byte>();
}

// Alternatively
private static Maybe<byte> OK()
{
    return ((byte)5).AsMaybe();
}
```

You need the `AsMaybe<T, TResult>` overload for value types that can convert to each other. For example when you do `5.AsMaybe()` it returns `Maybe<int>`, if your method's return type is `Maybe<byte>` you will need to convert `Maybe<int>` to `Maybe<byte>`, and the overload does that for you.

Now, the type conversion operator in `Maybe<T>` becomes redundant. And you can use `var` instead of full type name:

```
Maybe<int> obj1 = 5; // use operator
var obj2 = 5.AsMaybe(); // use extension method
```

Comment: This looks very cool indeed would be very useful fluent usage of extension method for functional programming style.

Answer (score 0):

You can't define a conversion to/from an interface type, If you change your example to use `List<T>` rather than `IEnumerable<T>` it will compile - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/conversions#user-defined-conversions

Comment: Uhh this is really annoying because I am heavily using Linq and need IEnumerable interface access so badly. And I think the link above you've sent describes something similar to the question in the link (which is not applies to my case IMHO, mine is more about an interface getting into the generic type field, not the conversion type is an interface) => https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5746161/how-to-write-implicit-conversion-from-an-interface-to-another-type

Comment: @EmirhanÖzlen: You are not the only one who misses this feature for their `Optional<T>` implementation. Have a look at https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/14186

Comment: @Heinzi I have started a bounty for the question. Seems like your answer is a good candidate. If you'd like you can write a general answer to the question. Thanks for the reference

Comment: @EmirhanÖzlen: I extended my comment into an answer and added the best workaround I could think of. Let's hope someone finds an even better solution. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Change this :

```
    private static Maybe<IEnumerable<byte>> NotOK()
    {
        IEnumerable<byte> a = new byte[] { 1, 2 };
        return a;
    }
```

into this :

```
    private static Maybe<IEnumerable<byte>> NotOK()
    {
        var a = new byte[] { 1, 2 };
        return a;
    }
```

The struct :

```
private struct Maybe<T>
{
    private readonly T value;
    private readonly bool hasValue;

    private Maybe(T value)
    {
        this.value = value;
        hasValue = true;
    }

    public static implicit operator Maybe<T>(T value)
    {
        return value == null ? new Maybe<T>() : new Maybe<T>(value);
    }
    
    public bool HasValue(){
        return this.hasValue;   
    }
    
    public T GetValue(){
        return this.value;  
    }
    
}
private static Maybe<byte> OK()
{
    return 5;
}
private static Maybe<IEnumerable<byte>> NotOK()
{
    Byte[] a = new byte[] { 1, 2 };
    Console.WriteLine(a.GetType().Name);
    return a;
}
```

Usage :

```
public static void Main(string[] args){
        
    var t1 = OK();
    var t2 = NotOK();
    
    Console.WriteLine("t1 type is "  + t1.GetType().Name);
    Console.WriteLine("t2 type is "  + t2.GetType().Name);
    
    if(t2.HasValue())
    {
        List<byte> search = t2.GetValue().Where(b => b > 0).ToList();
        foreach(byte num in search){
            Console.WriteLine(num); 
        }
    }
}
```

The reference `IEnumerable<byte> a` doesn't change the type, you can continue to `var` or `byte[]` and the query with `LINQ`, after, see in the full example

See the full example :
https://dotnetfiddle.net/V8RHQe

Comment: Nice catch. I'm surprised that this works, even through `Maybe<T>` is not covariant. Can anyone explain why?

Comment: Mhm. I think this works because my assumption is, the return is kinda doing some work behind the scene like first it converts Byte[] to Maybe<Byte[]> then it is compatible with Maybe<IEnum...> though the thing is meanwhile this answer is perfectly valid, can't solve my problem because I am strictly restricted to returning IEnum and this byte[] hack would only work on my simplified answer and not in product source code. I should have given a strict example of returning something from a LINQ query perhaps.

Comment: This is getting more complicated, it doesn't seems to be supported

Answer (score 0):

IEnumerable is an interface. Compiler does not know which type to work with. Put `ToList()` to end of your select like follows :

```
private static Maybe<IEnumerable<byte>> NotOK()
{
        var e = new[] { 1, 2, 3 }.Select(x => (byte)x).ToList();
        Console.WriteLine(e.GetType().Name);
        return e;
}
```

To understand what is happening try to create a method like follow in your class and watch compiler to cry :)

```
public static implicit operator Maybe<IEnumerable<T>>(IEnumerable<T> value)
{
        return value == null ? new Maybe<IEnumerable<T>>() : new Maybe<IEnumerable<T>>(value);
}
```